# fullpage.js: scroll to specific section (scrollOverflow enabled) in a section

Tags: fullpage.js

This is a bit tricky. I want to create an anchor that scrolls to a specific section in a section.

Say it scrolls to the last section, this section would have the normal scrolling effect because I have the `scrollOverflow` set to true. But I want to auto scroll to ONE SPECIFIC SECTION in the last section.

So essentially, it should involve two times scrolling:
**1st: Scroll to the last section** 
**2nd: Go to that specific section in the last section.**

```
<div class="section section__2">
  <a href="#specific-section">Scroll to specific section</a>
</div>
<div class="section section__3">
  // Inserting some content so that the page is long enough to see the normal scroll effect
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div data-anchor="specific-section">Content to auto-scrolled to</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using fullPage.js version 4? If so, that's possible. If not, not easy.

Comment: @Alvaro , I purchased it on February, so it is probably version 3. But the license keys for v3 doesn't work on v4, and since they are not fully compatible, changing the version might break a lot of things. So I guess I will be sticking with v3.
How would you suggest that I do this in v3 then?

Comment: It's not easy to do on version 3. The scrollOverflow feature works totally differently in there. It uses a vendor library for it. You'd have to get your hands dirty and figure it out by inspecting the code in the `scrolloverflow.js` file.

Comment: @Alvaro , I tried doing `setTimeout(function(document.getElementById('specific-section').scrollIntoView({behavior:smooth'})}, 700)`. All is working as intended, but the only bug is that after it is auto scrolled to a specific section, and I try to scroll up, it immediately scrolls to the previous section rather than normal scroll. It's like normal scroll stopped working and my last section is stuck at that position that it was auto scrolled to.

Comment: @Alvaro , after some inspections, it looks like the `fp-scroller`'s transform property isn't detecting the position of the smooth scrolling being scrolled to. Is there anyway to make sure that the `fp-scroller`'s transform property detects the smooth scroll position?

Comment: As I said, not easy on v3. I can only suggest you to move to v4.